# Cannot run meteor from a checkout because "No version of jquery satisfies all constraints: @1.11.10, @=3.0.0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

My app works fine with a normal Meteor installation.

But when I [run from a git checkout](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/DEVELOPMENT.md#running-from-a-git-checkout), I get the error that `No version of jquery satisfies all constraints: @1.11.10, @=3.0.0`. There is no referece to version `3.0.0` in either `.meteor/packages` or `.meteor/versions`. Running `$ meteor list --tree` doesn't show any reference either.

I saw [this forum thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/downgrade-jquery-in-meteor-1-9/51726) but none of the mentioned solutions work; jquery 3.0.0 is still being required from somewhere.

The complete error is:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  
   
   While selecting package versions:
   error: No version of jquery satisfies all constraints: @1.11.10, @=3.0.0
   Constraints on package "jquery":
   * jquery@1.11.10 <- top level
   * jquery@=3.0.0 <- top level
   * jquery@1.0.1 <- blaze 2.0.3 <- blaze-html-templates 1.0.4
   * jquery@1.11.4 <- msavin:mongol 7.0.1
   * jquery@1.0.0 <- iron:dynamic-template 1.0.2 <- iron:controller 1.0.2 <- iron:router 1.1.2
   * jquery@1.0.0 <- iron:location 1.0.2 <- iron:router 1.1.2
   * jquery@1.0.0 <- peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal 1.0.0
   * jquery@1.0.1 <- bartoftutormundi:tap-i18n 1.8.2
   * jquery@1.0.1 <- chrismbeckett:toastr 2.1.2_1
   * jquery@1.11.4 <- mdg:meteor-apm-agent 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that in the local Meteor checkout, `packages/non-core/jquery/package.js` lists its `version` as `3.0.0`. Simply changing it to `1.11.10` was enough to fix the problem.

This is harmless because this version number is really irrelevant. All this package does is export whatever `jquery` version was installed through `npm`.

Next, I ran into a similar issue with `coffeescript`, which I resolved the same way. (I'm less sure that this is harmless but in my case it caused no apparent issues.)

Comment: Thank you so much, probably not the most correct solution, but it saved me!